# Solving an equation having trignometric functions on RHS and an number in LHS

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving

> If $$\cos\frac\pi{2n}+\sin\frac\pi{2n}=\frac{\sqrt n}2, n\in\Bbb N,$$ find $n$.

I haven't been able to get an answer to this problem but I know that since the range of $$\sin x+\cos x$$ is $1,√2$
So the value of $n$ must lie between $4,8$.Ofcourse I can just check for all values but is there a way to do it analytically?

Comment: might be a sum $\to$ product

Comment: The range of $\sin x + \cos x$ is only $[1, \sqrt 2]$ in part of the domain, for example $0 \le x \le \pi/2$. Its full range is $[-\sqrt 2, \sqrt 2]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably steers away from the intention of the problem, but you can square both sides of the equation and take it from there.

\begin{align}
\cos\frac\pi{2n}+\sin\frac\pi{2n}&=\frac{\sqrt{n}}2\\
1+\sin\frac\pi n&=\frac n4\\
\sin\frac\pi n&=\frac n4-1
\end{align}

For $n\in\Bbb N$, we have LHS in range $(0,1]$.  This limits the possibilities of $n$ to $(4,8]$.  On this interval, $\sin\frac\pi n-\frac n4+1$ is strictly decreasing; therefore, there can only be one solution.  By inspection, $n=6$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}\cos\dfrac{\pi}{n} + \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}\sin\dfrac{\pi}{n} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2}\dfrac{\sqrt n}{2} $$

LHS is $$ \sin(\dfrac{\pi}{4}+\dfrac{\pi}{n})$$
with range $\pm 1$